# How to debug python in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Im little confused. I can not start debug python if vscode is not located on same folder with this script. But i can start it with "Run python file".

If i add to launch.json this text:

```
   {
 "name": "Python: Debug script",
 "type": "python",
 "request": "launch",
 "program": "${file}",
 "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
    }
```

then i can start debug it with Run And Debug button. How to make it works the "Debug python file" button?

Comment: what's the value of your `python.terminal.executeInFileDir` setting?

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that the **Debug Python File** options in the button do not use the configuration in *launch.json*. If you need to use the *launch.json* configuration to debug the script, you need to click the green triangle button on the **Run and Debug** panel, or use the `Start Debugging` or `Run Without Debugging` under the **Run** menu.

[image]

[image]

If you want to debug a specific script and configure the *[program](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_program)* option.

As for whether the play button in the upper right corner can be configured, there are several existing GitHub links you can view.

[Allow "Run Python File in Terminal" button to be configurable](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11812)

[VS Code and Python: configure the "Run" button next to the editor tabs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20746)

[List run configurations from the run button drop-down menu](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20269)

Comment: But i said that "Start Debugging" not works if script not in the same folder opened in vscode, can run only "Run Without Debugging". I dont know hot fo fix it :(

Comment: Where is this stated in your question? A detailed description of the problem will lead to a better solution.      Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As long as `program` is configured in *launch.json*, both `Start Debugging` or `Run Without Debugging` under the ** Run** menu can be used. If the script is no longer in the folder currently opened by vscode, use the **absolute path**.